# Usings $_GET to loop through a feed and find the right data

Tags: php, get

Im trying to set a working variable i can use later on in my code, ive got an `id` in the url that references an attribute in an external data feed. You can see a copy of the xml feed [HERE](http://whdn.williamhill.com/pricefeed/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=5&marketSort=HH&filterBIR=N)

the id comes in the url like this - `/page.php?id=52115351`

At the moment im setting my working variable as bellow, buts its just being set to the first instance of 'market' rather than being set against the instance thats got the same `id` as the one in the url.

```
  $wh_odds = $wh_xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market->participant;
  $wh_odds_attrib = $wh_odds->attributes();
  $wh_odds_attrib['name'];//name
```

How would i implement `$_GET['id']` with this block so that it would be making the working variable `$wh_odds_attrib['name']` from the participant of the correct instance of 'market' in the xml feed ?

Comment: I know all the words in the question but they way you use them they make no sense to me. I don't understand what you are trying to do there. If you want to get a node by id, consider using XPath. Here is a tutorial: http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using simpleXML you could try something like this:

```
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$marketNode = $simpleXml->xpath("/oxip/response/williamhill/class/type/market[@id='{$_GET['id']}']");
$attributes = $marketNode[0]->participant->attributes();

echo $attributes['name'];
```

Comment: With this do i still need to declare mu xml file like this ? - $simplexml = simplexml_load_file('xml/wh_f1_feed.xml');

Comment: cheers @skimsko, but it keeeps bringing up a bunch of errors, Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression (2nd line). Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed (2nd line). Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object (2nd line)

Comment: I updated the example. It should work. But please bear in mind, this is provided as an example to get you on the right track. It is not intended as a complete solution. You'll propbably want some checks in there, to make sure a node is actually selected etc. Use these links for reference. They contain everything you need to know to solve your problem: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are attempting to do but you can just assign the $_GET['id'] to whatever you want, ie $id = $_GET['id'] allowing you to use it in string manipulation (via sprintf or whatever).

A little more information about what you are trying to do, would help

Comment: actually all i want from it is the part $wh_odds_attrib['name'] from the block market 52115351

Comment: You are using a XMLparser? It should be pretty straightforward to get that node by ID, like @akimsko demonstrated for simpleXML in the other answer. You shoulnd't need $_GET as that can only catch the variables that are passed along in the actual URL.

Comment: yeah im using simplexml, loading it using simplexml_load_file then drilling down through it as above